# fixing div css layout

Tags: html, css

Help! anyone knows how to fix this issue in div layout?

i am trying to make a div layout which is not will going to overflow when the web browser is zoom in or out,

here is my example, when i zoom in the webbrowser it come's to..,
[image]

the "header right" going down at the left side of the "header left", what i want is the div "header left","header center","header right" is continue zoom in and there is scrorable in bottom so the content inside the div will not have an overflow, something like this...,
[image]

**here is my code;**

```
 **HTML**
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Help Div Fix</title>
 <link type="text/stylesheet" href="css_layout.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="header_div">
    <div id="header_left">Header Left</div>
    <div id="header_center">Header center</div>
    <div id="header_right">Header Right</div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>


 **CSS**
 body{
    margin:0;
    background:#EEF4F9;
 }
 #header_div{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
 }
 #header_left{
   float:left;
   height:50px;
   width:330px;
   background:#00F;
 }
 #header_center{
   float:left;
   height:50px;
   width:330px;
   background:#999;
 }
 #header_right{
   float:left;
   height:50px;
   width:330px;
   background:#666;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Minimum width for your parent header class.

```
#header_div{
width:100%;
float:left;
min-width:990px;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nHkm7/)

Comment: oh ok. i have modified my answer with jsfiddle. plz check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Set the left, center, right divs to `width: 33%;` and `min-height: 50px;`.

Comment: thanks for help, but the problem here is, i tried to write an 'input type="text"', and the width is 'width="350px"',and then i try to zoom in,the width of div is not stretchable,only the height,.. so the result, the input 'type="text"' is overflowing...mmm...problem not fixed. :-(